# Count look up values in excel

Tags: excel-formula

I have one defect list with part no and defect code

```
Blade No    Defect code
10          FR
10          FR
10          FR
11          FR
11          LD
12          ND
13          AR
10          TE
14          TE
14          TE
11          NT
16          LD
```

Now i want to count of defect except defect code TE against each blade number.

Comment: It's hard to understand what you're asking. Can you paste a screenshot of your data with an example of what value you want the formula to provide?

Answer (score 0):

Use a PivotTable and filter out `TE`:

[image: SO42031121 example]

Answer (score 0):

The [COUNTIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIFS-function-53C4DC8E-0E5B-4E32-93DF-9CA5E7DA89ED) can accept matching or non-matching criteria.

```
=COUNTIFS(A$2:A$13, D2, B$2:B$13, "<>TE")
```

[image]